# Add button after entity is persisted

Tags: forms, symfony

When I persist an entity I would like to add a button to the form. Is that possible. I read a lot about modifying the entity but this is not what I want to do, I just want to add a button.

```
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $em->persist($entity);
   .... what do I write here to add my button ? is it even here  or the type ?
```

Thank you
    }

Comment: You cannot modify the form after data has been set. Why not add the button as usual and choose not to display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is what it is but it is possible in fact. The formView has to be created before checking if the form has been submitted or is valid

```
$form_builder->add('button', 'boutons', array('attr' => array('boutons' => $buttons)));   //boutons is a type field I created and I have to give an array of buttons I want to add)
$form = $form_builder->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);
$form_view = $form->createView();

if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $form->getData();
    $em->persist($entity);

    if($form_view->offsetExists('button')) { 
         $form_view->children['button']->vars['attr']['boutons'][] = $button_send_validation; (// I add my new button to the array of buttons)
    }

}
```

Hope it can help someone..